# Parameterize @table annotation datastax cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How do I parameterize the table name annotated in a class ?
I have a table employee which has a model as

```
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
...
}
```

which is saved into Cassandra using mapper.
But soon we will migrate to another table in same keyspace "bt_employee" which has same structure. I am looking for a way to parameterize this table name instead of making the code change after table name gets changed.

I checked documentation and annotation's source code but cannot find relevant information.

I am using Datastax cassandra 3.1.1, Spring boot 1.2.7 and Spring core 4.1.8.